# BINARY - mysql . Для чего?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. При выборке из базы пользователей используется BINARY

```
db_query="select * from ".DB_PREF."users 
where BINARY name_user='".codeText($name_user)."' and BINARY password_user='".md5($password_user)."' ";
```

Объясните для чего это нужно и какие риски, если убрать (не будет учитывать регистр)?

Comment: скорее всего это писал очень неопытный разработчик (нет пробела перед `"users` - плохой стиль, `md5($password)` - так сто лет уже не пишут (пароли ваших пользователей уязвимы для подбора). Поскольку неизвестно чем руководствовался нуб,  советую вам убрать это и проверить. По идее должно все должно  работать по прежнему очень плохо.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут заметка [в мануале](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html), это сокращённый синтаксис для `CAST(str AS BINARY)`

В частности да, регистрозависимый поиск. Обратите ещё внимание на обработку оконечных пробелов. При этом, поле рассматривается как вычисляемое, т.е. становится невозможным использование индексов по этим полям.